# Matching a regular expression with a string (file name)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to differentiate between 2 files (in NSString format). As far as I know, this can be done by comparing and matching a regular expression. The format of the 2 jpg files which I have are:

**butter.jpg**

**butter-1.jpg**

My question is what regular expression can I write to match the 2 strings above? I've search and found an example expression, but I'm not sure how is it read and think it's wrong.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *exampleFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"butter-1.jpg"];

NSString *regEx = @".*l{2,}.*";    

NSPredicate *regExTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regEx];

if ([regExTest evaluateWithObject:exampleFileName] == YES) {
    NSLog(@"Match!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"No match!");
}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried using the following:

```
NSString *regEx = @"[a-z]+-[0-9]+.+jpg";
```

to try to match:

```
NSString *exampleFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"abcdefg-112323.jpg"];
```

Tested with:

abc-11.jpg (Match)

abcsdas-.jpg (No Match)

abcdefg11. (No Match)

abcdefg-3123.jpg (Match)

As of now it works, but I want to eliminate any chances that it might not, any inputs?

Comment: You need to explain your matching criteria in more detail.  Why not just say `[exampleFileName hasPrefix:@"butter"] && [exampleFileName hasSuffix:@".jpg"]`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for that. My criteria is that .jpg must be there, where as butter can be anything as long as it's an alphabet. However the hyphen and the digit must be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *regEx = @"[a-z]+-[0-9]+.+jpg";
```

will fail for `butter.jpg`, as it needs to have one `-` and at least on number.

```
NSString *regEx = @"[a-z]+(-[0-9]+){0,1}.jpg";
```

and if you do

```
NSString *regEx = @"([a-z])+(?:-([0-9])+){0,1}.jpg";
```

You can access the informations you probably would like to have later as capture groups.

> (...)   |Capturing parentheses. Range of input that matched the parenthesized subexpression is available after the match.

and if you dont need capture groups

```
NSString *regEx = @"(?:[a-z])+(?:-[0-9]+){0,1}.jpg";
```

> (?:...)| Non-capturing parentheses. Groups the included pattern, but does not provide capturing of matching text. Somewhat more efficient than capturing parentheses.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I forgot about butter.jpg. Do you mind explaining to me what {0,1} means?

Comment: `{0,1}` means *zero or one* appearance

Comment: @vikingosegundo: No, but I can see that some of the capturing groups will capture crap.

Comment: `?` also means zero or one appearance and is shorter and more common.

Comment: Dawson's not going to access any capture groups if he's using `NSPredicate` to do the matching.

Answer (score 2):

You can match an alphabetic character (in any language) using `\p{L}`.  You can match a digit using `\d`.  You need to escape the `.` because in a regular expression, `.` means “any character”.

Parsing a regular expression is expensive, so you should only do it once.

```
BOOL stringMatchesMyPattern(NSString *string) {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static NSRegularExpression *re;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:
            @"^\\p{L}+-\\d+\\.jpg$" options:0 error:NULL];
    }

    return nil != [re firstMatchInString:string options:0
        range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
}
```